# Flow is not collected in Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Im creating a Flow inside my repository which fetches data from an sse api

```
override fun getStream() = flow {
    try {
        val response = api.getStream()
        while (true) {
            //do something with response
            emit(result)
        }
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        ..
    }
}
```

It get forwarded into my composable where the viewmodel gets injected

```
@Composable
fun FirstPage(
    viewmodel: myviewmodel = hiltViewModel()
)
```

The flow then gets collected like this

```
val eventStream by viewmodel.getStream().collectAsState(initial = "Loading"))
```

But in this scenario, the flow does not get collected. If i emit something before the try block, the value will show, but nothing from inside of it.

I know the api call is working, because when i collect the flow inside my viewmodel, the data shows.

Comment: Your SSE call will only be called once. Is that intended?

Comment: If i add a log right underneath the emit command, i can see messages getting received. but they are emitting to my composable